# Is there a better way to explore the Python Standard Library with a proper Class Browser in PyDev/Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

I'm able to browse to my Python System Libs .py files in Eclipse's Package Explorer, but the experience leaves much to be desired from there.

How can I use Eclipse and PyDev to be a proper class browser of the Standard Library as I'm learning Python?  The closest that I'm getting to is the ability to browse and open the library's .py files.  I would like to see not only the a hierarchal view of the library by categories in the reference manual (String services, Numeric, File & Directory Access, IPC, et al) but also click on the class to see methods, available parameters, and descriptions.

Edit:
Take a look at what IDLE has: a hierarchal view of the module with a view of classes and methods.  I'm looking for something like this in PyDev:

[image]

Compare the same pickle.py when imported in Eclipse.  Only a view of the module, not classes or their methods.  This isn't an issue for me for my own code - I can clearly see the classes, functions, and objects that I write in Eclipse.  I can even look up specifics for the library in the Globals Browser.  But it would be much better if could find a way to have this available in Package Explorer or any other window.

[image]

The best example I can think of in an IDE is the Class View or Object Explorer in Visual Studio - in it, Microsoft had all their libraries to explore - and with wonderful documentation.

**To be clear, I know *how* and *where* to access the standard library via pydocs, online reference, etc.  I'm looking for a much more integrated experience.

Comment: When you're exploring with python, the [ipython](http://ipython.org/) or [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org) shells can be very helpful. They'll let you tab complete and look at help in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you and that is very similar to what I'm doing currently: using help(), modules, etc.  I think I'll start using ipython.

Comment: Just to note, you can use the console integrated in PyDev for that: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that right now in the current PyDev Package Explorer...

Now, if someone would be interested in implementing that in PyDev, it'd be a matter of extending the method getChildren() from https://github.com/aptana/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/src_navigator/org/python/pydev/navigator/InterpreterInfoTreeNodeRoot.java for the use-case where it's not a dir or zip-file to try to parse it and create the proper nodes.

( provided the code is properly gotten following instructions from: http://pydev.org/developers.html )

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options that I'm aware of, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

You can browse here: http://docs.python.org/library/index.html
and that will give you everything in the standard library.

Also, depending on your system, you can find those same html file and view them locally. On my Fedora box they are stashed at /usr/share/doc/python-docs-2.7.3/html/index.html (don't forget to yum install python-docs)

Comment: Thanks.  Revised question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the python doc server that ships with python, then navigate to:

```
http://localhost:7464
```

In windows its in the start menu called "Module Docs"

Comment: Thanks, revised question to clarify.